# TypeScriptで出力されるJSファイルのインデントを2スペースにしたい

Tags: typescript

タイトルの通りです。
tsconfig.json を使っています。
出力後の JavaScript のインデントが 4 スペースになっていて
これを、2スペースにしたいのですが設定方法が不明です。

ググっても出てきませんでした。(試しにやってみてくださいな)

設定方法ご存知の方、教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScriptコンパイラ本体（`tsconfig.json`）には**そのような設定はありません**。[そのような設定が欲しいという提案が以前にありましたが、却下されています](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4042)。

目的を達成するには出力されたjsファイルにさらに別のツールをかませて調整する必要があります。[js-beautifier](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify)や[prettier](https://prettier.io/)がよいでしょう。

Comment: うわ！そうなんですね。
出力後のものを整形するという考えは思いつきませんでした。
出来ないことを出来ないと知ることができて助かりました。ありがとうございます。